# Unmapping keys in IdeaVim

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, ideavim

I tried to map Numpad 1 to a key combination in PHPStorm Idea VIM using the following command:

:map k1 keycombination

Now actually k+1 is mapped to the key combination. When navigating using the K key, the system waits for extra input after the K, which is very annoying.

I tried to unmap the combination, but the command ":unmap k1" doesn't work. When I check the keybindings using the :map command, the k1 mapping is still there.

I couldn't find any documentation regarding this. Does anybody know how to unmap keys in Idea VIM?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this, I've just figured it out today:

`:map k k`

There should be definitely an `unmap` command in ideavim anyway!

Comment: Alas, I have the same problem, though I have mapped "//" to clear my search highlights, which is really annoying as "/" to start a search now doesn't work properly. Unfortunately re-maping single "/" as suggested here doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue: By restarting PHPStorm, the mappings where removed.

Before the IDE crashed and I had to close it using the killall command, that's why the keymappings set using the :map command weren't reset.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround:

```
map k :action VimCancelExEntry<cr>
```

Seems like `VimCancelExEntry` hasn't any side affect (in normal mode at least).

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing by accidentally pressing `:map h`.  I closed WebStorm and reopened it and it went away.